# Get observed variable from another component and redraw when changed

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

In my project I have two nodes (svg boxes) and a connection between them (arrow).

Node is a components, that is initialized by passing `x` and `y` coordinates as a props:

```jsx
let nodes = [];
nodes.push(<Node key={0} x={50} y={100} />);
nodes.push(<Node key={1} x={300} y={100} />);
```

Now I have a `Connection` component, that should take two parameters: a `Node` to connect from and a `Node` to connect to:

```jsx
let connections = [];
connections.push(<Connection key={1} from={nodes[0]} to={nodes[1]} /> );
```

`Node` is defined as `@observer` and have two observable properties

```jsx
@observer
export default class Node extends React.Component {

    @observable left = 6;
    @observable top = 8;

    ...
}
```

You can drag-and-drop `Node` and `left` and `top` values will change accordingly.

`Connection` component is also defined as `@observer` and passed in props of nodes we need to connect are bound to observable variables:

```jsx
@observer
export default class Connection extends React.Component {

    @observable node_from;
    @observable node_to;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.node_from = this.props.from;
        this.node_to = this.props.to;
    }
    ...
}
```

`Nodes` and `Components` are then gets rendered inside parent's `render()` method like so:

```jsx
render() {
    let nodes = [];
    nodes.push(<Node key={0} x={50} y={100} />);
    nodes.push(<Node key={1} x={300} y={100} />);

    let connections = [];
    connections.push(<Connection key={1} from={nodes[0]} to={nodes[1]} /> );

    return (
        <div>
            <svg width={600} height={400}>
                {connections}
                {nodes}
            </svg>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now my problem is that I cannot figure out how to modify my `Connection` component so it gets notified whenever one of the nodes passed to it "changes" (meaning its `left` or `top` got changed) so that I can redraw a line between nodes?

Basically I have two problems:

1. Be able go get `left` and `top` variables of `Node` from inside `Connection` component (to determine coordinates from what x;y and to what x;y I should draw a line);
2. Redraw only a `Connection` upon moving `Node` that connect only node being moved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question for new person coming in the React world.

There's really no good way to "listen" for changes of another component. And that's alright, because it would be an anti pattern in react.

What you want to do instead, is move the control of the x and y coordinate outside the `Node` component an into a parent component. This parent component will control both nodes positions and update the `Connection` arrow between them based on their position.

When siblings needs to know about themselves, that always means you want to move the property control one level up.

Comment: when I was reading about mobx I thought it was like a key feature about it - you can define what should be observable and make actions on any other component that observes observables.. how that parent component you were talking should track changes then?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to add this as comment, but try following.

```
class NodeStore {
  constructor(x,y){
    extendObservable(this, {x, y});
  }
}

class ConnectionStore {
  constructor(source, target){
    extendObservable(this, {source, target});
  }
}

@observer
class Node extends React.Component {
  render(){
    ...
  }
}

@observer 
class Connection extends React.Component {
  render(){
    ...
  }
}

@observer 
class Paint extends React.Component {
  @observable connections = [];
  @observable nodes = [];
  render(){
    const {connections, nodes} = this;
    return (
      <svg width={600} height={400}>
        {connections.map( connection => <Connection {...connection}/> )}
        {nodes.map( node => <Node {...node}/>)}
      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

Basically, keep store outside of the react component.